# Отображение активного элемента при открытии сайта

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, новичок в этом деле. Подскажите как отобразить активный элемент или же просто первый по списку блок li при открытии сайта.

```js
$('.sto-nav li').on('click', function() {
  var targetBlock = $(this).data("content");
  $('.' + targetBlock).show().siblings(".hide").hide();
});
```

```css
.content .hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sto-nav">
  <ul class="sn">
    <li data-content="b1" class="active hvr-underline-from-center">О нас</li>
    <li data-content="b2" class="hvr-underline-from-center">График работы
    </li>
    <li data-content="b3" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Схема проезда
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="b1 hide">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b2 hide">
    </div>

    <div class="b3 hide">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в *JS*, раз уж Вы используете *JQuery*:

```
$('.b1').addClass('active');
```

Класс `active`:

```
.active{
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Добавить обработчик на нажатия `li`:

```
$('.content').find('div').addClass('hide'); //прячем все остальные div
var targetBlock = $(this).data("content"); //выбираем элемент
$('.'+targetBlock).removeClass('hide'); //убираем класс hide
```

А вообще, советую Вам использовать в своей работе [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Там уже есть готовый, нужный Вам [функционал](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp).

Comment: Благодарю! вместо bootstrap осваиваю css grid + ко всему хочу научиться этому самому, просто некогда литературу читать